# Dobbs Murder Mystery: A Picture worth 1000 words?

Tags: situation

Detectives Kirk and Singh were looking at the crime scene where Ken Dobbs lay dead on the ground. They were certain that it was a murder because of the stab wounds and the blood all over the crime scene. There was no murder weapon.

Dobbs was one of the 2 owners of the contracting firm D & I (Dobbs and Irwin). Ken Dobbs was killed in the office and was found almost simultaneously by his partner Daniel and the executive assistant Chris when they showed up for work around 9 AM. It was also interesting to the detectives that a disgruntled customer Tommy Wilson also showed up just after 9. To complete the suspect list Ken’s ex-wife Trish had left several hateful messages on his voice mail regarding alimony payments and child custody. The detectives also found a blood splattered business card of D&I in Dobbs’ hand on which he seemed to have scribbled a few letters before he died.

After talking to all the Persons of Interest, the detectives summarized their findings as below:

- Dobbs was murdered between 8 and 9 AM that day
- Chris was having an affair with Dobbs but recently they had a bad break up
- The firm was having financial issues and Irwin blamed most of them on Dobbs’ crazy spending habits.
- Tommy had several public rows with Dobbs because he did not finish the bathroom remodel job. Tommy claimed that Dobbs and the firm owed him 5K$
- All except Tommy lived within 1 mile of the office. Tommy said he took the bus this morning which was a 1 hour ride. He showed a ticket punched at 8:10 AM that day departure time. This was verified.
- Nobody else had alibi.

The detectives concluded that Dobbs knew his killer and tried to write it down on the business card. Kirk suspected Tommy but Singh was not sure.

Who did it?

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification, I'm assuming Daniel's full name is "Daniel Irwin," and these are not two separate people?

Comment: I called that number, and the guy on the other end of the line seemed pretty upset that I would accuse him of murder.  I would have e-mailed instead but g*ail.com could basically be anything.

Comment: Daniel Irwin. That is correct

Comment: I see a little part of the beginning of the m and the end so it is most likely gmail.com

Comment: Rot13(Vf gur crapvy znexvat ba gur pneq gur erfvqhr bs BC qensgvat gur oyhr jevgvat, be fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu gur cybg? Va cnegvphyne, vs gur yrggre nobir gur ynetrfg fgnva vf z, gur crapvy qensgvat vf abg. Jung vf gur oyhr jevgvat gelvat gb pbaprny?)

Comment: not important @ weathervane. But the content is

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The murderer is:

> Daniel Irwin

The murdered Dobbs has tried to relay this message by writing:

> "d this to me" after the company initials 'D & I'

This translates to:

> "**D and I d** this to me" or "**Dan did** this to me" once the spaces are rearranged.

Motive:

> *The firm was having financial issues and Irwin blamed most of them on Dobbs’ crazy spending habits.* With Dobbs out of the way, Irwin believed he could then try to get the company's finances back on track. Furthermore, Irwin was still upset at Dobbs having messed up his name on the company's official business cards ("Isac?? Do you even *know* my surname, Ken??") - hardly cause for murder by itself, but definitely a symptom of an unhappy working relationship...

A note on execution:

> Perhaps Irwin timed the murder for this particular day knowing full well that Dobbs had recently received threatening messages from Trish and that Tommy (possibly) had an appointment with the management at 9 to discuss his complaints, immediately creating two main suspects for the murderer. After committing the crime Irwin then intended to double back from the crime scene before opening hours so that he could walk in with his assistant Chris at 9am and be seen to have an alibi. Unfortunately for Irwin, Tommy overslept and missed his regular bus which would have put him at the scene of the crime at the right time. Once the police enquiries exonerate Trish, it's only a matter of time before the net closes tighter around the nefarious Irwin...

Comment: Maybe Isac was his *new* partner, and Irwin just found this out?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry - it's a possibility, I grant you. Maybe Isac is a variant of executive assistant Chris's surname and Irwin is actually being replaced by singer-songwriter Chris Isaak?! Man, that would bum me out... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe that's weird, but in my opinion the killer is:

> nobody!!! He just committed suicide.

explanation:

> Write on the card: "i do this to me"-I -Meaning "I" and not a clue to another person's name,And i can understand him he went through hard days, both in his personal life and at work,He was also ashamed and tried to disguise that he had written it beforehand And tried to imitate a shaky manuscript(you can see pencil under letter m) as well as tried to stain it with his blood in a way they think he was murdered -Because if he was indeed murdered the blood should have been in the heart / head / lungs area and not in his hand so it drips onto the page.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was

> Tommy.

This is because

> Some of the writing has the words “it is Tom” on it. Further, the bus ride was an hour long but Tommy showed up just after (to me, this means less than 10 minutes after) 9am, even though the bus left at 8:10am. He could have also gotten someone else to ride the bus or buy the ticket, bus tickets aren’t ID-specific. Further, the business card didn’t come from inside the organization — I can’t imagine Irwin would be too happy if his company’s business cards misspelled his name as Isac.

Comment: I thought Tommy too, but the bus ticket could be red herring...

Comment: "Kirk suspected Tommy **but Singh was not sure**."

Comment: I think the business card thing was the most important part — and the fact that it was misspelled seems like it wasn’t just grabbed from inside the office, @Duck

Comment: So it could not be Chris or Irwin or Daniel? Trish could have been so angry, she misspelled his name...

Comment: Trish could have planted the card as fake evidence it was Tommy.

Comment: @Duck It seems doubtful that Trish would even know Tommy outside some contrived circumstances.

Comment: I think Daniel Irwin is one person, @Duck

Comment: Probably, but I feel like something is too obvious about Tommy...

Comment: And a customer would be more likely to know who Dobbs and Irwin are than Trish, so she could have guessed it was Isac.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed the note that Tommy had *public* rows with Dobbs, so it is very possible that Trish is familiar with him and is aware of a possible motive

Comment: Yes and Trish waited until right after the murder to call him (since it went to voicemail) which conveys the feeling that she wasn't there at the time of the murder. (or Dobbs didn't pick up the phone)

Answer (score 1):

I think it was

> Irwin

Because

> the card could read.... I did this to me, where I is the I in D & I

maybe because

> of the misspelled name on the card? :)